# Calculate Translation Repetitions

Tags: string, translation, repeat

I have looked around the web for the standard formula for calculating repetitions in a document to be translated.  I have not found it.  For those who don't know what repetitions in translation means, [this](http://www.proz.com/forum/poll_discussion/233680-poll%3A_do_you_apply_discounts_for_repetitions.html#2023766) gives a good description of it.

I first tried something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collection.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
<snip>
Dictionary<string, int> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
int CalculateRepetitions(string plainTextDoc) {
    foreach (string item in Regex.Split(plainTextDoc, "\\P{L}+"))
        if (_dict.ContainsKey(item))
            _dict[item]++;
        else
            _dict.Add(item, 0);
    return _dict.Where((key, value) => value > 0).Count();
}
```

but that was not close to the sample number from Trados for the same document, and was the wrong definition of repetitions anyway.  Does anyone have a good example for calculating translation repetitions?  I'm not expecting only C# answers, I'm good with java and c++ answers as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [GMX/V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_information_management_Metrics_eXchange) standard might be your answer and there seems to be a [C# implementation](https://code.google.com/p/gmx-v/).

Comment: The specification mentions that repetitions are 100% repeated segments, so that solves that issue.  Also mentions the standard for word count, which I think you can use Regex to get.  Thanks.